# MySQL Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, join

Hi I need to generate an sql query by joining two queries

1st Query : Getting all students data

```
SELECT * FROM students where class = 1 and section = 'A'
```

[image]

2nd Query : Getting the count of each attendance

```
SELECT  roll_no,full_name, 

SUM(hasAttended= 'P') AS DaysPresent, 

SUM(hasAttended= 'A') AS DaysAbsent, 

COUNT(*) AS totalClasses

FROM     attendance

GROUP BY roll_no
```

[image]

NOW I need to join the two tables and produce a resultant table

I am trying the following query but getting an error :

> ## 1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

My Query is as follows :

```
SELECT * FROM students as st

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT  att.roll_no,att.full_name, 

SUM(att.hasAttended= 'P') AS DaysPresent, 

SUM(att.hasAttended= 'A') AS DaysAbsent, 

COUNT(*) AS totalClasses

FROM     attendance as att

GROUP BY att.roll_no)

ON st.roll_no = att.roll_no

ORDER BY  st.roll_no
```

Can anybody please solve the above error

Comment: you need to give the second table for the inner join its own alias. GROUP BY att.roll_no) should be followed by an alias.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MySQL requires that all derived tables and subqueries have an alias.  You are missing an alias at the end of the closing parentheses for the subqquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM students as st
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT  att.roll_no,att.full_name, 
    SUM(att.hasAttended= 'P') AS DaysPresent, 
    SUM(att.hasAttended= 'A') AS DaysAbsent, 
    COUNT(*) AS totalClasses
  FROM     attendance as att
  GROUP BY att.roll_no
) att  ---------------------------< this is missing
  ON st.roll_no = att.roll_no
WHERE st.class = 1 
ORDER BY  st.roll_no
```

Comment: Thats it ??!!! OMG feel so dumb for asking this question. Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: Also if I have to join a where clause for the table students [WHERE class = 1 ].. then where do I need to add it ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally subqquery needs an alias name as above. Also I had a problem which was solved. You can see my solved query. i.e.

```
SELECT SUM(total_items) AS sum_total
FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(imt.item_id) AS total_items
    FROM item_master_tbl imt
    INNER JOIN map_category_item_tbl mci 
                ON imt.item_id=mci.item_id
    INNER JOIN category_master_tbl cmt 
                ON mci.category_id=cmt.category_id
    GROUP BY cmt.category_id) alias_name;
```